# How to add an image file to a project ( Resources) by typing code not by dragging and dropping

Tags: c#

How to add an image file to a project ( Resources) by typing code not by dragging and dropping

```
byte[] byteImage;

if (pictureBox1.Image == null || name.Text == string.Empty)
{
    byteImage = new byte[0];
    MessageBox.Show("قم بالتاكد من ادخال كل البيانات اولاً واختيار الصورة ", "عملية الاضافة", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
else
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
    byteImage = ms.ToArray();

    MessageBox.Show("تمت عملية الاضافة ", "عملية الاضافة", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: *" by dragging and dropping "* - you probably mean adding the file to project as resource. It's not clear what you want instead *"by typing code"*. Do you want to hardcode the image in the source?

Comment: You want to add files to app's resources at run-time?